# An identity relating to the linearization of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x$ be a solution to $x'(t)=f(x(t)), x(0)=x_0$, where $f(0)=0$ and $\text Df(0) = A$. Apparently ([page 5](http://perso.univ-lemans.fr/~apopier/enseignement/stabileq.pdf)):

$$x(t)=e^{At}x_0 + \int_0^te^{A(t-s)}(f(x(s)) - Ax(s))ds\tag{1}$$

But I really don't see why. I tried to write

$$x(t)=e^{At}x_0 + \int_0^t\frac{d}{ds}(x(s)-e^{As}x_0)ds$$

But no matter how much I fiddle with it, I can't get the derivative of $x(s)-e^{As}x_0$ to match the integrand in (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Start with:
$$ \left( e^{-At} x\right)' = e^{-At} (f(x) - A x) $$
and integrate this from $s=0$ to $s=t$.